# New Box iOS SDK sample app issue

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, box-api

I exactly followed this video tutorial for integrating BOX in iOS and performed the same steps in the website (http://developers.box.com/box-ios-sdk-tutorial/). After building the application I got  the following content in the simulator " Error:redirect_uri_mismatch " and my console shows the following :

[image: console error message]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting a `redirect_uri_mismatch`, chances are that you've entered in a `redirect_uri` in the Box developer app console.  The SDK already handles this for you and only requires the client secret/client id be set.  In the app console, leave the `redirect_uri` blank like in the image attached and everything should be good to go.[image]

Comment: Thanks. now i got a another issue after authentication in web view my simulator displays a white screen its not showing my view controller.

Comment: The page throws error "OAuth2 redirect URL must specify a valid URL and must not be http://" if I leave the field "redirect_uri" blank.

Answer (score 2):

Except that you can't leave it black.  The page won't let you save the settings if that field is blank.

Answer (score 0):

**Providing an answer to this question just in case somebody else runs into the same issue in the future.**

In case of "Error:redirect_uri_mismatch", Box recommends to fill out the redirect_uri in the following format at [Box developer page](https://developer.box.com).

> Find the 'redirect_uri' field in the 'OAuth2 Parameters' section. Make sure it is populated with the expected format: boxsdk-YOUR_CLIENT_ID_HERE://boxsdkoauth2redirect. This is needed for authentication to work in your app. The SDK expects this pattern. Make sure you replace the 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID_HERE' string with your client ID value from the 'client_id' field. The dash ('-') remains.

Source: [Box Github page](https://github.com/box/box-ios-sdk/blob/master/doc/Setup.md)